# Elasticsearch and Searckick: Unable to get partial match on a joined field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, join, partial, searchkick

I am trying to implement elasticsearch on Rails using Searchkick.

The goal is to search on 5 field of order, 2 of which are joined fields, and ideally partial matches using word_middle

```
For search_data

class Order < ApplicationRecord

searchkick word_middle: [:po_number, :tracking_number]  #Works
#searchkick word_middle: [:po_number, :tracking_number, :purchaser.name]  #does not work

...

def search_data
attributes.merge(
  order_content: self.order_content,
  ship_name: self.purchaser,
  vendor_name: self.vendor,
  po_number: self.po_number,
  tracking_number: self.tracking_number 
)
end
```

And in the actual search:

```
search_query = Order.search "#{search_query}", where: {archived: false},fields: [{po_number: :word_middle}, {tracking_number: :word_middle}]

#search_query = Order.search "#{search_query}", where: {archived: false},fields: [{po_number: :word_middle}, {tracking_number: :word_middle}, {ship_name: :word_middle}]  #Did not work
```

I can get the expected search results for PO_NUMBER and Tracking_Number, but when I try to include ship_name or purchaser.name   I don't get any matches including ones that should match on PO and tracking numbers

Comment: I have re-indexed after making any changes.   So what I am struggling with is how to add I am supposed to list 2 fields and one joined field as word_middle for partial matches on any of those fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
# searchkick word_middle: [:po_number, :tracking_number, :purchaser.name]  # does not work
```

Shouldn't the `:purchaser.name` be `:ship_name` which matches the field you imported & searched in the ElasticSearch?

Comment: At one point I thought so too, but I get an error when trying to build the index if I use :ship_name in above.